# Medicine for Aquarium Fish wound

Tags: aquarium, fish, diseases, medicines, community-aquarium

Any tips on how to treat the fish's wound in the linked photo, including what medication to use?

Additionally, I'm new at making fish and I've only had my new fish for three days. I only became aware of the wound at home, and now I want to treat the fish, but I have no idea what to do. I need an expert's advice or assistance in order to determine the specific nature of the illness and the best course of action.

TIA[image: fi]

Comment: i am sorry to say this but your fish is too injured by a fungal infection to be saved.i want you to take a look here https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm reading and understanding how to cyclle a tank will help you keep your next fish alive a lot longer than the one in your picture.

Comment: Did the injury occur before you got the fish, or during his time in your tank? Check for anything sharp he may have caught himself on. Does he have tank mates that may have injured him? What kind of fish is it, and what are the tank parameters (size, heated, filtered, ammonia/ph readings, etc.)? I might look into goldfish ulcers too.

Comment: @Gwendolyn The fish was like this from the aquarium shop. I treated him with Meth Blue in the hospital tank but sadly it passed away. All the parameters was good in the tank.

Comment: @mapmalith I'm so sorry to hear it. Regardless, you saved him from the shop, and gave him your best care and comfort for his last days.